# Tracking form properties besides fields

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux-form

I have a multi-page form, using a vertical tabs UI, in redux-form, and I'd like to track the current tab selection in the redux-form store.

What's the best way of doing this?

- I would track the current tab selection outside of redux-form, but I've integrated redux-form with [redux-undo](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo), and I'd really like for undoing a form change to go back to the tab of the modified control.
- I tried using a `selected` redux-form field, but this means that changing the selected tab marks the form as dirty.
- From reading the docs, I could probably use [reducer.plugin](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/docs/api/ReducerPlugin.md/) to add arbitrary properties to the redux-form store, but I don't see any documentation of which arbitrary property names are "safe," and I'd have to update the plugin for every form that should behave this way.

Any ideas?